# Angular2 oidc-client not clear the cookies for mvc application when i logoff from angular2 app

Tags: angular, identityserver3, oidc-client-js

I have an authorization server which is currently being utlized by both my angular2 app and the mvc webapp.

I have implemented authorization in angular2 app using oidc-client javascript package. Everything is working fine except logout functionality.

```
public logoff(): void {
    this.customAuthService.startSignoutMainWindow();
}

startSignoutMainWindow() {
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
        return this.manager.signoutRedirect({ id_token_hint: user.id_token }).then(resp => {
            console.log('signed out', resp);
            setTimeout(5000, () => {
                console.log('testing to see if fired...');
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
};
```

This is the code that I'm using to logout my angular2 application which is using oidc-client to implement authorization.

But this is not logging out my other asp.net web mvc application.

But the reverse is working fine i.e. if I log out of my mvc web application, my angular application redirects to the authorization server for login in.

Can anyone help to fix this so that if I log out of my angular2 app, I should be able to use mvc application without login again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your log say, when you hit logout on the angular app? Do you have a successful message in the log?

Comment: For clearing the session you need to do some extra operation on complete logout.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initiate logout:

   ```
   let userManager = new Oidc.UserManager(oidcSettings);
   public startLogout(): Promise<any>
           {
               return this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
           }
   ```
2. complete logout

   ```
    public completeLogout(url?: string): Promise<any>{

       return this.userManager.signoutRedirectCallback(url)
           .then((user: OidcClientUser) =>
           {                  
               // This will clear the OpenID access tokens that is stored in the session
               return this.userManager.clearStaleState();
          });                 
   }
   ```

On logoutComplete you need to clear session and clientDeeplinks from browser
something like this:

```
  public clear(ClientDeepLink?: string): void
        {
            if ((key) && (key.trim().length > 0))
            {
                this.$window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
            else
            {
                this.$window.localStorage.clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please let me know where to make the call to completeLogout()? an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have written logOUtController that initates the logout window when user click on logout button.
You need to define these steps in your controller and initiate request from there.